# Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00401000, Win32 error 0n299

Tags: windbg

I tried to debug a sample using WinDBG. First I removed "WinDBGSample.pdb", and then I tried to set a breakpoint at the entrance of `main()`, but I failed.

I don't know what's wrong with my options. If you know, please give me some advice.

The error detail:

[image: error message]

start address of `main()`:

[image: start address]

Comment: Google "address space layout randomization".

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is telling you that 00401000 is not a valid address yet so you need to set an unresolved breakpoint using 'bu', and then once that address is available it will set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bp main` instead of hard-coded address.   It is possible that the program is loaded at a different address.   As Hans commented, ASLR could change the start address of the module.  If for some reason you cannot use a PDB file, use the `lm` command to see the base address of the module and calculate the location of `main` based on that.

Comment: thanks, John. And I have another question:when I execute "bp main", there are errors:"*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for WinDBGSample.exe
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\system32\MSVCR100D.dll -"(I put symbols in "C:\Symbols" and I have set Symbol Path); Of curse, I can execute "g" normally.

Comment: use a fully qualified symbol name in the form module!function e.g. WinDBGSample!main